# understanding a lemma in a proof that the axiom of choice implies zorn's lemma

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

> I'm having some trouble understanding the proof of Lemma 2 on page 4 of [these Axiom of Choice notes](http://www.borisbukh.org/MathStudiesAlgebra1718/notes_ac.pdf). To ensure I understand the material, I was wondering if the following justifications are correct:

- $A\backslash A'$ and $A'\backslash A$ are nonempty (as otherwise the minimum would be undefined).
- $A$ and $A'$ are well-ordered, so since $A\backslash A'$ is a nonempty subset of $A$, it has a minimum and similarly for $A'\backslash A.$
- $C\subseteq A'$ because if not then $\exists x \in C\backslash A'\subseteq A\backslash A',$ but then $x \prec z = \min A\backslash A'$. This is a contradiction, so no such $x$ exists.
- $z = \min A\backslash C$ because $A\backslash C$ is the set of all elements that are $\succ $
- All elements of $C$ precede $z$, so since $A$ is a chain, every element in $A\backslash C$ is at least $z$ (or succeeds it).
- Since $z = \min A\backslash C$ and every element of $A\backslash C$ is an upper bound for the elements of $C, z = f(Upp(C)) = g(C).$

> However, I have a few questions:

- Why are $A\backslash A'$ and $A'\backslash A$ both nonempty? Why can't $A' = A$?
- Why does $A'$ being a chain imply that $x\prec z'$ for all $x\in C$?
- If $x\prec z'\,\forall x \in C,$ why does this imply that $C$ is a proper initial segment of $A'$? I get that $C\subseteq A',$ but why does this show that $\forall x \in A', \forall y \in C', x \prec y \Rightarrow x \in C'$?
- If $C$ is a proper initial segment of $A',$ why does this show that $g(C)\in A'$?
- If $z' \not \prec z,$ doesn't this just mean $z' \succ z$ as $A$ is a chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are assuming that $A\nsubseteq A'$; this is exactly equivalent to saying that $A\setminus A'\ne\varnothing$. Similarly, $A'\nsubseteq A$ means that $A'\setminus A\ne\varnothing$. These set differences aren’t non-empty because otherwise their minima wouldn’t exist: their minima exist because they are non-empty.

Your next two bullet points are correct.

Your fourth bullet point is incomplete. $z\in A\setminus A'\subseteq A$, and each $x\in C$ satisfies $x\prec z$ and hence $x\ne z$, so $z\in A\setminus C$. For any $x\in A\setminus C$ we have $x\not\prec z$, and $\prec$ well-orders $A$, so $z\preceq x$, and therefore $z=\min(A\setminus C)$. This also covers your fifth bullet point.

I don’t understand your sixth bullet point: $A$ is an attempt, and $C$ is a proper initial segment of $A$, so by definition $g(C)=\min(A\setminus C)=z$.

Now for the questions. We are assuming (in order to get a contradiction) that $A\nsubseteq A'$ and $A'\nsubseteq A$; each of these alone already implies that $A\ne A'$.

In second question we are considering the case in which $C\ne A'$. Let $x\in C$. Then $x\prec z$, so if $z'\preceq x$, we have $z'\preceq x\prec z$ and hence $z'\prec z$, contradicting our assumption that $z'\not\preceq z$. Thus, we must have $z'\not\preceq x$ for every $x\in C$. Now recall that $z=\min(A\setminus A')$, and that $x\prec z$ for every $x\in C$; this means that $x\in A'$ for every $x\in C$, i.e., that $C\subseteq A'$. And $z'\in A'$, so for each $x\in C$ we must have at least one of $x\preceq z'$ or $z'\preceq x$. We’ve already ruled out the latter, so we must have $x\preceq z'$ for each $x\in C$. Finally, $C\subseteq A$, and $z'\notin A$, so $z'\notin C$, and therefore $x\prec z'$ for each $x\in C$.

Clearly $C$ is a proper subset of $A'$, since $z'\in A'\setminus C$. Suppose that $x\in C$, $y\in A'$, and $y\prec x$. Then $y\prec x\prec z'$, so $y\prec z'=\min(A'\setminus A)$, and therefore $y\in A$. Since $x\in C$, we also have $y\prec x\prec z$, so $y\prec z$. Thus, $y\in A$ and $y\prec z$, so by definition $y\in C$. It follows that $C$ is a proper initial segment of $A'$.

$A'$ is an attempt, and $C$ is a proper initial segment of $A'$, so by definition $g(C)=\min(A'\setminus C)\in A'$.

Finally, the fact that $A$ is a chain says nothing about $z'$, since $z'\notin A$. In particular, $z$ and $z'$ could be incomparable: it might be that $z'\not\preceq z$ **and** $z\not\preceq z'$.

Comment: So, just to clarify, for any $x\neq z\in A\backslash C,$ since $x \not \prec z$ and $A\backslash C$ is a chain (every subset of a chain is a chain), $x \succ z,$ so no $x\neq z$ can be a minimum element. Since a minimum element in $A\backslash C$ exists (every subset of a well-order has a minimum element), $z$ must be the unique minimum element. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @FredJefferson: No misunderstanding: that’s correct.